# Auto-loading file on program startup

Tags: c#, autoload, save

Ok, so here's a bit of code. I'm having an issue where I want to save to a pre-defined location, and I want to have a pre-defined name for a file. Neither FileStream nor StreamWriter allows you to set both of those paramters as far as I can tell, based on what I've seen on MSDN.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("PermaServerList", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter hiddensw = new StreamWriter(@"Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments", false);
```

So, if you look at that, how would I get it to save a file called "PermaServerList" to the location "My Documents", regardless of the version of Windows they're using? I don't want to hard code in a location, I want it to always be whatever My Documents is in their particular version.

Alternatively, the idea behind this is that every time the program starts, I want it to load the list they last saved automatically. Is there a -simple- way to do this? Right now, the idea is that I'll just save to their chosen location, and then make a second copy in my pre-defined location and just load that on program startup. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "PermaServerList.txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName)) {
    writer.WriteLine("wooo");
}
```

That's how you'd write to the file, for example. The `SpecialFolfer` enum will get you the location of the "My Documents" directory every time, regardless of what version of Windows they're using, or whether the folder is mapped to a network location, etc.

I'm not sure what you mean by "load the file when the program starts"; I assume your issue is that you need the directory location, beyond that it's just a question of opening it as a stream and working with it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're simply trying to store and read user data, which can be easily dealt with using [app.config settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: or he can use Application Settings which handles Object<T>

Comment: yep true. Here is the msdn link for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx